# How did Billy become eligible to gain Shazam's powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, shazam

When the ancient wizard Shazam summons children to test them and find a champion, he judges them based on their will to resist the temptations of the Deadly Sins. He deems every one of them unworthy because they are enticed by the Eye of Sin.

But when Billy is summoned by the wizard, the Eye of Sin and the Deadly sins are already gone. So on what basis does Shazam decide that Billy is "pure of heart"? Is it because Billy helped Freddy by hitting the bullies? If that one incident made him pass the test, aren't there a lot of kids who are eligible to get the powers? Or is it that the wizard was running out of time and chose Billy based on that one good deed?

Comment: When Billy points out that he is not good and pure, and isn't sure that there is actually anyone who is, the wizard says: "You are all I have." So it seems like the wizard is simply running out of time to keep looking for the right person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early in the movie, Shazam tests Thadeus Sivana for a pure heart. Disappointed in Sivana's failure, Shazam casts some kind of tracker spell which he commanded to find people of pure heart.

They do not go in to details about what this tracker spell does. Presumably though, it hunts down potential candidates based on their actions and reports them back to Shazam. Shazam then would teleport them to him where he does the final test.

Though it's not shown in the movie, we can assume that the tracker spell found Billy and reported Billy's actions to Shazam. Shazam ordinarily would test Billy like the others, but Sivana had already taken the Seven Deadly Sins. Shazam chose Billy out of pure desperation because there was simply no more time (it's been 30 years as it was). However, the tracker spell had already told him that Billy at least had *some* potential to be pure, so he wasn't pulling just anybody off the street.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have already pointed out, the wizard ran out of time and was left with only one choice. The AMC Special Edition comic helps slightly, by showing that Billy (inadvertently?) convinces the wizard that he at least has potential.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Scene 1:** Wizard casts a spell to find out pure hearts.

**Scene 2:** Dr Sivana comes to take the Eye of Sin. and one of the seven sins utter that the wizard is very weak and won't/can't stop him.

**Scene 3:** When Billy is summoned by the wizard *(or the tracker spell automatically summons the potential chosen ones, I don't know)* the Eye of Sin was gone and wizard literally turned into ashes after he passed on his power to Billy.

These scenes put up (dominantly) that wizard was just putting his faith on the purity of the kid in front of him, as there was no more time left for looking other candidates.

> Oh hey! this can be example for kids to write in tests as an example
>   for "being at right place at right time"

This Reddit post ([Can someone explain to me why the Wizard gave Billy Batson, a kid, the powers and responsibility of being Shazam?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/a7un60/shazamdc_can_someone_explain_to_me_why_the_wizard/)) & this Looper post ([What does it meant to be pure of heart exactly?](https://www.looper.com/149582/confusing-shazam-moments-explained/)) Also suggest the aforementioned theory.

Now I don't think there is any explanation available on this, as there are too many variables (questions) floating around. Was Billy the first to get summoned after Sivana took the Eye? Why did Wizard turn to ashes, was that meant to be regardless him giving powers to someone? and so on...

So overall my conclusion is: **Wizard was running out of time & Billy was his *(potential)* pure heart candidate**.